# Openlayers custom control div position and visibility does not appear on map

Tags: openlayers

I want to createa a sample custom button to appear on my openlayers map.

```
 <div id="map" class="map">
   <div class="ol-custom ol-unselectable ol-control">
     <button class="ol-zoom-in" type="button" title="Show Me">O</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And my css is like this

```
.map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
.ol-custom{
  top: 4.5em;
  left: .5em;
}
```

But my custom button does not appears. I used openlayers css classes that used for other controls but did not work.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w1uzatqj/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS should be like this (by adding the z-index), it's also preferable to add (position) but not required.

```
.map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
.ol-custom{
   z-index: 1000;
  top: 4.5em;
  left: .5em;
}
```

[Your DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w1uzatqj/12/)

The Z-index determines the rendering order; [[Example]](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-z-index.html)

Comment: why do we need z-index? Default css classes of openlayers des not include z-index. For example `.ol-zoom {top:.5em;left:.5em}`

Comment: @barteloma As you said that Default CSS with just the zoom is shown without z-index and as the DEMO shown in your question. but when you tried to add additional button, you need to show it over the layer (base map) so in this case, we need z-index.